# How to convert int (yyyymmdd) to timestamp in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive, amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift and have a field in a table as type int representing a day's date. For example the int is *20180215* . The format is yyyymmdd.

I would like to know what is the most efficient way to convert this int to a timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) using SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_timestamp().`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html)

```
select to_timestamp(20180215::text, 'YYYYMMDD')::timestamp

    to_timestamp     
---------------------
 2018-02-15 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

The function returns `timestamp with time zone`. The result depends on the current time zone setting. You can cast the result to `timestamp` to skip the time zone part.

Comment: If the input is an int, then first convert it to a string to do the above, such as: `select to_timestamp(col1::TEXT, 'YYYYMMDD');`

Comment: Thanks. If I convert the int to string and then to timestamp, do you see any performance degradation? I'll be doing this to billions of records and interested in optimal sql

Comment: @codeshark It will have an impact, but it is very fast compared to a read from disk. If you intend using the date as a date, then it is best to import the data directly into a date field during the ETL process.

Comment: Thanks . Also, how to make sure the timestamp is UTC? For example 20180215 should create timestamp 2018-02-15 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best

```
import datetime
date_format = "%Y%m%d"
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime("20180215", date_format).timestamp()
timestamp
# 1518620400.0
```

you make this better by making function

```
def date_2_timestamp(date):
    from datetime.datetime import strptime
    return strptime(date, "%Y%m%d").timestamp()
```